# can someone please explain why this keeps crashing on iOS 4.2?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4, gdb, ipad

The code worked in iOS 3.2 and in 4.2 it keeps crashing.

Here's the line that it crashes on.

```
NSArray* address = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[[[access.filteredResults objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] addressArray] objectAtIndex:0]];
```

---

```
2010-11-04 12:20:03.060 ContactMapper[2211:207] -[__NSCFDictionary  getObjects:range:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5648e30
2010-11-04 12:20:03.062 ContactMapper[2211:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary getObjects:range:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5648e30'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0117abe9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x012cf5c2 objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0117c6fb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x010ec366 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x010ebf22 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x01176605 -[NSArray initWithArray:range:copyItems:] + 245
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x010e1367 +[NSArray arrayWithArray:] + 119
    7   ContactMapper                       0x00003a8d -[RootViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 1333
    8   UIKit                               0x0033a7fa -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 634
    9   UIKit                               0x0033077f -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:] + 75
    10  UIKit                               0x00345450 -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 1561
    11  UIKit                               0x0033d538 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 242
    12  QuartzCore                          0x01fc2451 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 181
    13  QuartzCore                          0x01fc217c CALayerLayoutIfNeeded + 220
    14  UIKit                               0x005c7702 -[UISplitViewController willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:] + 1134
    15  UIKit                               0x00373df2 -[UIViewController window:willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:] + 962
    16  UIKit                               0x002edee5 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 1783
    17  UIKit                               0x002e8538 -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:duration:force:] + 89
    18  UIKit                               0x002eb643 -[UIWindow _updateInterfaceOrientationFromDeviceOrientation:] + 164
    19  Foundation                          0x000306c1 _nsnote_callback + 145
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x01152f99 __CFXNotificationPost_old + 745
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x010d233a _CFXNotificationPostNotification + 186
    22  Foundation                          0x00026266 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 134
    23  UIKit                               0x00477d0a -[UIDevice setOrientation:animated:] + 228
    24  UIKit                               0x002c9637 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 656
    25  UIKit                               0x002d3db2 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1533
    26  UIKit                               0x002cc202 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 71
    27  UIKit                               0x002d1732 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
    28  GraphicsServices                    0x01ab0a36 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x0115c064 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x010bc6f7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x010b9983 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x010b9240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x010b9161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    34  UIKit                               0x002c8fa8 -[UIApplication _run] + 636
    35  UIKit                               0x002d542e UIApplicationMain + 1160
    36  ContactMapper                       0x00002638 main + 102
    37  ContactMapper                       0x000025c9 start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, this line is your problem:

```
[NSArray initWithArray:range:copyItems:]
```

at first glance, it might be that you need indexPath.row not [indexPath row].

Because iOS 4.2 is still under NDA, we cannot talk about 4.2-specific code.
We can however, talk about 4.1 and previous.

First, you're going to go to the 4.2 diffs page after you sign into the iOS Dev Center. This will tell you what's changed in that release. Since these pages only show release to release, look at the 3.2-4.0 diffs, 4.0-4.1 and 4.1-4.2 diffs. You are looking for a change in the API for UITableView or NSArray that obviously cannot be talked about here.

Second, you're going to download the WWDC '10 session on crash reports. It's a little tedious but the hour spent learning about how to read a crash report is WELL worth it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting tells you that the selector `getObjects:range:` is being sent to an `__NSCFDictionary`.  So clearly the following:

```
[[[access.filteredResults objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] addressArray] objectAtIndex:0]
```

... used to return an NSArray, but is now returning an NSDictionary.

I don't know what `access` is so I have no idea what else to say other than you can change the line you cited as the source of the error to:

```
NSDictionary* address = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[[[access.filteredResults objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] addressArray] objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Once you've done that, whatever code follows that uses `address` clearly needs to also change to deal with the fact that you're no longer accessing an array.

Answer (score -1):

You need the new iOS CookBook code